# How can I print from WebForms App after published on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis-10

Im trying to print from an app that I've published on IIS. It does not show any error

Running on Visual Studio prints fine.

I've read that is something about permissions but I have not found a solution yet. I Use a class to print automatically.

(Note: my pc will be my server, I will use the app only in my computer )

```
public static void Print()
    {
        if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
        }
        else
        {
            printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
            m_currentPageIndex = 0;
            printDoc.Print();
        }
    }

public static void PrintToPrinter(this LocalReport report)
    {
        Export(report);
    }

    public static void DisposePrint()
    {
        if (m_streams != null)
        {
            foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
                stream.Close();
            m_streams = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please tell me which kinds of error you have faced after you pushed to the IIS?  Is this web form application is used to print the reprot form reprot viewer control?

Comment: @BrandoZhang Im facing no errors, I mean  when i click the button that triggers the printing, it starts normally like its going to print but the document never arrive to the printer. And yes is used to print from report viewer control

Comment: How do you have the IIS AppPool set up? You likely need to run it as a user who has permission to print (I don't know that off the top of my head because frankly this seems like a security nightmare).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I set it to run with network service, local system and defaultappPool, always the same. I went to the printer and in the security tab added the user and still does not work.

Comment: Did you try setting it to run as yourself?